# Afraid of getting denied or

Tags: phrase-usage

Afraid of getting denied.

Scared to be denied.

Which one is grammatically correct please tell me.

Comment: Neither one is a complete sentence.

Answer (score 2):

"Afraid of being denied" is grammatical and idiomatic. "Scared to be denied" is not idiomatic and probably is not even grammatical. "Scared of being denied" is grammatical and idiomatic but slightly colloquial.

I cannot say as a provable fact (though I believe it to be fact) that "scare" plus a **passive** infinitive is never grammatical in current American English, but I can say that it is very rare. Of course, "scare" plus an **active** infinitive is quite common.

Comment: If the second one was _scared of being denied_, however, that would be fine. It’s really a poorly-worded question, in that the first word is different in each, and the second part is also structured differently in each, making it hard to do a compare and contrast.

Comment: Yeah, it is, J.R.; however, I think one can use "scared + to-infinitive", but not what he has above, which is "scared + to-infinitive + past participle". For instance, I see nothing wrong with, "I'm scared **to go** with you." "I'm scared **to move**." Jeff Morrow gives a great explanation of this passive infinitive and active infinitive phenomenon.

Comment: @fusion the best way of thanking someone is by accepting their answer, just click on the grey checkmark beneath the bottom arrow, it's only visible to you, when you click on it, it changes to green and becomes visible to everyone. You also get a small surprise when you accept an answer.